# Подскажите как переписать модель RNN LSTM

Tags: keras

Изучаю прогнозирование времянных рядов с помошью нейронных сетей(Keras). Реализовал модель, которая удовлетворяет моим требованиям.(Ниже будет описана работа модели).
Нейронная сеть работает следующим образом:
Имеется времянной ряд, со значениями **{ *V_i* }**, ***1 <= i <= n***, где ***n*** - длинна датасэта. Для прогнозирования ***k***-го значения ***V***, необходимо подать на вход нейронной сети ***look_back*** - предыдущих значений, где ***1 <= look_back <= inf***, т.е. ***V_k = F( V_(k-1), V_(k-2), ... , V_(k-look_back))***, где ***look_back < k <= n***, ***F*** - функция построенная внутри НС. Следовательно для прогнозирования  будущего значения ***V*** на шаге ***f***(future), нам необходимо подать следующую последовательность: ***V_f = F( V_(f-1), V(f-2), ... , V_(f-look_back))***, где ***n < f < inf***. Пример: ***f = n+2*** и ***look_back = 3*** , тогда ***V_f = F(V_(n+1), V_n, V_(n-1))***, но т.к. ***V(n+1)*** неизвестно, т.е. это будущее значение, которое выходит за рамки датасэта, то представим это значение в виде ***V_(n+1)*** ***= F(V_n, V_(n-1), V_(n-2))***, тогда  исходная запись примет следующий вид ***V_f = F( F(V_n, V_(n-1), V_(n-2)), V_n, V_(n-1))***. Применяя такую логику НС дает не достаточно точный прогноз. Хочется улучшить результат изменив логику следующим образом: Прогнозировать не одно будущее значение за раз, а скажем последовательность будующих значений за раз, т.е. подать на вход look_back - предыдущих значений, а на выходе получить последовательность подряд идущих будующих значений.
ВОПРОС: Как я должен изменить модель нейронной сети и данные , что бы НС удовлетворяла новой логике? Не понимаю как можно это сделать в коде. Ниже приведена реализация НС по первой логике.

```
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, LeakyReLU, Dropout, 
BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import keras.regularizers as regularizers
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tqdm import trange

numpy.random.seed(7)

def load_dataset(datasource: str) -> (numpy.ndarray, MinMaxScaler):
    # load the dataset
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv(datasource, usecols=[1])
    dataframe = dataframe.fillna(method='pad')
    dataset = dataframe.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

    # normalize the dataset
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
    return dataset, scaler



def create_dataset(dataset: numpy.ndarray, look_back: int=1) -> (numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray):
    data_x, data_y = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        data_x.append(a)
        data_y.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(data_x), numpy.array(data_y)

def split_dataset(dataset: numpy.ndarray, train_size, look_back) -> (numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray):
    if not train_size > look_back:
        raise ValueError('ERR')
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size look_back:len(dataset), :]
    print('train_dataset: {}, test_dataset: {}'.format(len(train), len(test)))
    return train, test

def build_model(look_back: int, batch_size: int=1, regularizers_value: float=0.1) -> Sequential:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1,
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1)))
    model.add(LSTM(64,stateful=True,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(16,return_sequences=False,stateful=True,activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularizers_value)))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    return model

def plot_data(dataset: numpy.ndarray,
              look_back: int,
              train_predict: numpy.ndarray,
              test_predict: numpy.ndarray,
              forecast_predict: numpy.ndarray,
              regularizers_value: float):

    plt.plot(dataset)
    plt.plot([None for _ in range(look_back)] +
             [x for x in train_predict])
    plt.plot([None for _ in range(look_back)] +
             [None for _ in train_predict] +
             [x for x in test_predict])
    plt.plot([None for _ in range(look_back)] +
             [None for _ in train_predict] +
             [None for _ in test_predict] +
             [x for x in forecast_predict])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(str(regularizers_value)+'-regularizers_value ' + 'look_back - '+str(look_back)+'plt')
    plt.show()

def make_forecast(model: Sequential, look_back_buffer: numpy.ndarray, timesteps: int=1, batch_size: int=1):
    forecast_predict = numpy.empty((0, 1), dtype=numpy.float32)
    for _ in trange(timesteps, desc='predicting data\t', mininterval=1.0):
        # make prediction with current lookback buffer
        cur_predict = model.predict(look_back_buffer, batch_size)
        # add prediction to result
        forecast_predict = numpy.concatenate([forecast_predict, cur_predict], axis=0)
        # add new axis to prediction to make it suitable as input
        cur_predict = numpy.reshape(cur_predict, (cur_predict.shape[1], cur_predict.shape[0], 1))
        # remove oldest prediction from buffer
        look_back_buffer = numpy.delete(look_back_buffer, 0, axis=1)
        # concat buffer with newest prediction
        look_back_buffer = numpy.concatenate([look_back_buffer, cur_predict], axis=1)
    return forecast_predict

datasource = 'in_data.csv'
dataset, scaler = load_dataset(datasource)
original_dataset = dataset
regularizer_value = 25
#dataset = dataset[:int(len(dataset) * a_iter / 100)]
# split into train and test sets
#look_back = int(len(dataset) * a / 100)
look_back = 24
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.85)
train, test = split_dataset(dataset, train_size, look_back)

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
train_x, train_y = create_dataset(train, look_back)
test_x, test_y = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
train_x = numpy.reshape(train_x, (train_x.shape[0], train_x.shape[1], 1))
test_x = numpy.reshape(test_x, (test_x.shape[0], test_x.shape[1], 1))

print(numpy.shape(train_x))

# create and fit Multilayer Perceptron model
batch_size = 1
model = build_model(look_back, batch_size=batch_size, regularizers_value=regularizer_value/100)
for _ in trange(100, desc='fitting model\t', mininterval=1.0):
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()

#model.save(str(regularizer_value)+'-regularizers_value ' + str(look_back) + '-look_back  ' + str(1) + '-epoch ' + 'MODEL - STATEFUL')
#model.save_weights(str(regularizer_value)+'-regularizers_value ' + str(look_back) + '-look_back  ' + str(1) + '-epoch ' + 'WEIGHTS - STATEFUL')

# generate predictions for training
train_predict = model.predict(train_x, batch_size)
test_predict = model.predict(test_x, batch_size)

# generate forecast predictions
forecast_predict = make_forecast(model, test_x[-1::], timesteps=60, batch_size=batch_size)

#if numpy.isnan(train_predict[0][0]):
#   continue
print(look_back)
# invert dataset and predictions
dataset = scaler.inverse_transform(dataset)
original_dataset = scaler.inverse_transform(original_dataset)
train_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predict)
train_y = scaler.inverse_transform([train_y])
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict)
test_y = scaler.inverse_transform([test_y])
forecast_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(forecast_predict)

# calculate root mean squared error
train_score = numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(train_y[0], train_predict[:, 0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % train_score)
test_score = numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_y[0], test_predict[:, 0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % test_score)

if len(original_dataset) > len(dataset):
    plot_data(original_dataset[int(len(train_predict * 0.9)):len(dataset) + 10], look_back,
              train_predict[int(len(train_predict * 0.9)):],
              test_predict,
              forecast_predict,
              regularizers_value=regularizer_value)
else:
    plot_data(original_dataset[int(len(train_predict * 0.95)):], look_back,
              train_predict[int(len(train_predict * 0.95)):],
              test_predict,
              forecast_predict,
              regularizers_value=regularizer_value)
del model
```

Спасибо за внимание.